# What does the Cycliq "Universal" Adaptor connect to?

Tags: camera, smartphone-mount

I have a couple of Cycliq cameras that use this 1/8 turn connector. What type of connector is the other end (the two protrusions with a hole through them)?

[image: Side view of Cycliq Universal Connector]

[image: Front view of Cycliq Universal Connector]

Photos taken from https://www.wildfiresports.com.au/cycliq-universal-adaptor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two circular holes will mount to a Go-Pro type mount. This is clever as the Go-Pro mount is available for a wide variety of surfaces include suction cups, helmet mounts, sticky mounts, handlebars, selfie poles and the like.

[image: go pro mount kit]

---

Notice the adapter has two tabs and a hole.  That's a "downward" facing part, so its to go into a matching part with three tabs and the bolt/nut for retention.

Here's a gopro camera showing the two downward tabs in clear plastic:

[image: http://img.dxcdn.com/productimages/sku_316619_8_small.jpg]

So your adapter is intended to have the circle side facing upward, to mount the Cycliq light onto a gopro mount on the bike, not to mount a camera.

Comment: Go-pro mounts are becoming quite standard now for action cameras and other accessories.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like a variant of Garmin cycling GPS mount:

[image: garmin mount]

However, your mount has four notches, not two. Maybe it is compatible with something else.

EDIT: Googling for the names and images reveals what this adapter is compatible with - Cyclic's own lights:

[image: light]

[image: light too]

Source: https://www.dcrainmaker.com/2017/11/cycliq-fly6ce-fly12ce-first-look.html

Comment: Thanks, but the question is what the *other* end connects to.